# web scraping a website in php is not working

Tags: php, web-scraping, get

I want to get the Currencies Table​​​ data from this [link](http://www.cibeg.com/English/Pages/CIBCurrencies.aspx) but I can't get the data in the table ... I had tried different ways but all in vain

the library that I'm using: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

here is the php code:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html("http://www.cibeg.com/English/Pages/CIBCurrencies.aspx");
$c = $html->find("#divCurrTableContainer",0)->innertext; 
echo $c;
```

Comment: it returns nothing however when I change  the url to https://www.wikihow.com/Host-Your-Own-Website-for-Free and the $c variable to $c = find("#intro",0)->innertext;   it returns the content

Comment: what you mean by bank terms ?

Comment: Can you please share what `$c` returns? need more information. What had you tried so far? Can you post some sample HTML from your source site? Are you trying to get live currency information? You can use some API! also read the site terms before you perform web scrapping.  Here some API that might help [fixer.io](http://fixer.io) and ask your google friend [qry:Live Currency API](https://www.google.com/search?q=live+currency+api)

Comment: This site fills the div you're trying to read with javascript after the site loads (CIBCurrencies.aspx line 965). My guess is that the library you're using tries to grab the div too quickly

Comment: @wpcoder thanks but do you know what's the problem in this bank

Comment: @Asthmatic thanks so how do I solve it ?

Comment: anyway, your selector is wrong: Open Chrome browser, go to developers tools F12, then highlight the element and right click then copy selector, in your code, it should be `#divCurrTableContainer > table`

Comment: thanks @wpcoder ... when I change the selector the same way that you commented I get " Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: dont scrape, use an API

Comment: scraping is fine, the problem was that the site was filling that div asynchronously

Comment: @nogad thanks but the bank doesn't provide an API

Comment: there are other API's - scraping can be: illegal, immoral, against terms, break easily when the source changes, be blocked

Comment: Try to adjust your topic line and make it objective, currently its so generic. See stack help for asking question tips.

Comment: @wpcoder OK Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that their site uses to get the information in that table:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/_layouts/15/LINKDev.CIB.CurrenciesFunds/FundsCurrencies.aspx/GetCurrencies',
        async: true,
        data: "{'lang':'" + document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl48_g_5d7fc52f_a66d_4aa2_8d6c_c01fb4b38cb2_hdnLang").value + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d != null && msg.d.length > 0) {
                var contentHTML = "<table class='currTable' cellspacing='0' rules='all' style='border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;'>"
                        + "<tbody><tr class='currHeaderRow'>"
                            + "<th scope='col'>" + document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl48_g_5d7fc52f_a66d_4aa2_8d6c_c01fb4b38cb2_hdnCurrency").value + "</th><th scope='col'>" + document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl48_g_5d7fc52f_a66d_4aa2_8d6c_c01fb4b38cb2_hdnBuy").value + "</th><th scope='col'>" + document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl48_g_5d7fc52f_a66d_4aa2_8d6c_c01fb4b38cb2_hdnSell").value + "</th>"
                        + "</tr>";

                for (var i = 0; i < msg.d.length; i++) {
                    if (msg.d[i].CurrencyID.length > 0) {
                        contentHTML += "<tr class='currRow'>"
                                + "<td>" + msg.d[i].CurrencyID + "</td><td>" + msg.d[i].BuyRate + "</td><td class='lastCell'>" + msg.d[i].SellRate + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                    }
                }
                contentHTML += "</tbody></table>";
                $("#divCurrTableContainer").html(contentHTML);
                if ($(".bannerElements").length > 0)
                    FixCurrenciesRatesScroll();
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
        }
    });
```

In php, we can replicate this request with curl:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.cibeg.com/_layouts/15/LINKDev.CIB.CurrenciesFunds/FundsCurrencies.aspx/GetCurrencies');

$data = array("lang" => "en");                                                                   

$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
  'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       

);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);

?>
```

paste this into http://phpfiddle.org/ and see the result you get back, which you'll have to parse with php

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciated but what was the problem ?

Comment: Their ajax request was run after document.onload, and sets `async: true,`. Your library was grabbing the site after the document loaded, but before the asynchronous request was returned

Answer (score 1):

### How to find proper selector:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

in Chrome Browser:

1. Press F12
2. Open Elements Tab
3. Select the html tag
4. Right click and go to copy then Copy selector

Your code should work with this selector: `#divCurrTableContainer > table`

```
$c=$html->find('#selector_here');
foreach($c as $element)
echo $element->innerText();
```

and as @nogad pointed, use API for live data...scrapping won't help in this type of data as its changing over time.

Some references:

Here some API that might help [fixer.io](http://fixer.io) and ask your google friend qry:[Live Currency API](https://www.google.com/search?q=live%20currency%20api)